# How to know whether the solution of an indefinite integral can be written in the form of elementary functions or not?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Yesterday, I saw a definite integral here. That question is deleted now. I am writing it as indefinite integral $\int \left ( \frac{2log_{e}x}{x+1} - \frac{log_{e}x}{4-x} \right )\; dx$. I tried to solve this integral using substitution and integration by parts and thought more about it but didn't get the solution. I checked on WolframAlpha where it is showing the solution as  $2 Li_{2} (-x) + Li_{2}\left ( \frac{x}{4} \right ) + log_{e}x\left ( log\left ( 1-\frac{x}{4} \right ) + 2log(x+1) \right ) + \; constant$, where $Li_{n}(x)$ is the polylogairthm function.

Can anyone please explain how to know whether the solution of an indefinite integral can be written as elementary functions like trigonometric, exponential, logarithmic etc or not ? Is there any method for it ? Thank you.

Comment: It is not an easy topic, but there are some useful results. See the [Risch algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm). There is also some theory related to [differential algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_algebra) and [Liouville's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(differential_algebra)).

Comment: Thank you so much. @TobErnack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of elementary functions, it could be difficult.

Consider $$I=\int \frac{\log (x)}{x+a}\,dx$$ Change variable $x=a(t-1)$ to make
$$I=\int \frac{\log (a (t-1))}{t}\,dt=\int \frac{\log (a )}{t}\,dt+\int \frac{\log  (t-1)}{t}\,dt$$ that is to say
$$I=\log(a) \log(t)+\int \frac{\log  (t-1)}{t}\,dt$$ and now we need some special functions.

Comment: Sir, Thank you.  I asked about the procedure to check whether the solution is in elementary functions or not. I mean, is there any simple procedure to check whether the solution of the given indefinte integral can be written in the form of elementary functions or not ?

Comment: @ankit. Tob Ernack gave the right comment. By the way, you are welcome !